# Are there any decent scripting languages that use functional programming?

Tags: scripting, functional-programming

I've been reading a bit about functional programming recently and am keen to get have a bit of a play. are there any decent scripting languages that support functional programming? I find that the bulk of my ad-hoc programming is done in Python, so I thought I might be able to do the same with a functional language. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Lua](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_(programming_language)) appears to fit your needs:

> Lua (pronounced /ˈluː.ə/ LOO-uh) is a
>   lightweight, reflective, imperative
>   and functional programming language,
>   designed as a scripting language with
>   extensible semantics as a primary
>   goal.

Comment: I had a look at Lua this weekend...what a cool language...a lot like python in terms of ease of use. I like it :)

Comment: A related alternative would be to use [MoonScript](http://moonscript.org/), a "programmer friendly language that compiles to Lua".

Comment: Lua is much more of a dynamic language than a functional language. But see https://github.com/luafun/luafun

Comment: @Lassi Dynamic does not preclude functional. Take Erlang, for example.

Answer (score 6):

[Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org) can also be used as a scripting language. It runs on the JVM and supports both imperative OO and functional programming. Using this you can have access to the entire Java class library.

Comment: Scala *should* be a good language for scripting .. but scala scripts are a bit clunky due to the header mechanics and non-negligible load time.

Answer (score 4):

GNU's [Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/guile.html) can be used as a stand-alone script interpreter, see [this FAQ entry](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/docs/faq/guile-faq.html#How-do-I-make-foo_002escm-into-an-executable-script_003f) for the details. Not sure how much general programming support is in Guile, though, but it could at least get you started quickly with something that should look and feel like a "traditional" functional language.

Comment: GNU Guile is the official extension language of the GNU project.  Be sure to check out 2.0 which also can compile (to byte code) JavaScript and Elisp.

Answer (score 3):

Python can be written in a functional style, as can JavaScript.  If you mean something more purely functional, then you could try Haskell.

Comment: Can you please expand on how Python can be written in a functional style? Also Haskell is not meant for scripting, afaik it is compiled and not interpreted.

Comment: Python is quite non-functional in structure and  pythonistas / zen of python imposed approaches to problem solving is almost militantly imperative . Just try to do fluent programming in python.. there are some libraries that try to plug the gap but they are not really mainstream (with exception of maybe _dask_)

Answer (score 3):

Perl can do functional style programming very well. It isn't a pure functional language by any means, but it supports quite a lot of functional idioms. The classic full-length treatment is Mark Jason Dominus's [*Higher Order Perl*](http://hop.perl.plover.com/), which is now available freely online.

For briefer introductions, take a look at these slides:

- [Functional programming in Perl](http://perl.plover.com/yak/fp/)
- [Introduction to functional programming in Perl](http://perl.jonallen.info/talks/functionalprogramming)

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin is a practical *functional* language, mainly for the JVM.  It has a scripting flavor called *kscript*.  I've used it for shell scripting in personal projects.  Simple example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env kscript

args.forEach { arg -> println("arg: $arg") }
```

Run it:

```
  > ./example.kts hey you
  arg: hey
  arg: you
```

Drawbacks:

- Requires JVM
- Slow startup

For more info:

- https://github.com/holgerbrandl/kscript
- Search stackoverflow for `kscript`

If you're comfortable with the JVM and like functional programming, *kscript* is worth exploring.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "scripting language." It isn't commonly viewed that way, but many Scheme implementations [seem to fit the bill](http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/languages/scheme/tutorial-dsitaram/t-y-scheme-Z-H-17.html) as well as Python, and Lisp is sort of the archetypal functional language.

Answer (score 1):

I recently work on a functional scripting language and already finished the first version. It is a bit like a haskell/perl combination and therefore nice for scripting and mathematical problems, too.
For example here is a code snippet demonstrating how easy it is:

`5 times {echo["Iteration: " concat str[x]]}`

If you are interested, you can give it a try: http://ac1235.github.io

Answer (score 0):

Julia language. Also not just a "scripting" language, as fast as C.

See my answer here: [https://www.quora.com/Whats-a-good-scripting-functional-programming-language/answer/Páll-Haraldsson](https://www.quora.com/Whats-a-good-scripting-functional-programming-language/answer/P%C3%A1ll-Haraldsson)